# How do i assign results of a function compute to a variable in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I collected data from a database using  laravel's eloquent. I need to convert a DATETIME value to a timestamp. i did that successfully but cannot assign it back to the result. It;s been giving me a headache. The code snippet is below.

```
public function getArticle() {
    $article = new Article;
    $data =  $article::find(Input::get("article_id"));
    $data->created_at = $this->getTimestamp($data->created_at);
    return $data;
```

}

the function to convert the datetime to timestamp is below:

```
public function getTimestamp($datetime) {
    $time = strtotime($datetime);
    return $time;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: "but cannot assign it back to the result." - why? is something or somebody preventing you from writing the code for that?

Comment: "$data->created_at = $this->getTimestamp($data->created_at);"  What are you trying to do there? It is just copying the same time back to itself?

Comment: If you are having trouble, try outputting `$data->created_at` using var_dump before and after your function call to see if it has the values  you are expecting.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange `It is just copying the same time back to itself?` it is setting a variable after it goes through the function call.

Comment: Yes - but the function call is to return a strtotime, from a timestamp that is *already* on that object. So it is not actually doing anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Laravel Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) uses [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon). You dont need to convert anything - it can be done on the result automatically:

```
printf("Right now is %s", $data->created_at->toDateTimeString());
```

There are many other ways to manipulate the Carbon option. [You can see a full list here at the Carbon Github page](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent).